# How do I Print class,sub property and range at one row using owl API?

Tags: java, rdf, owl, ontology

I need to print [Class] - [Class sub-property] - [Class range] also [Class super property] in one line using owl API.

I have tried but I am only getting [class] and it's [sub-property]

below is my code :

```
package com.ifour.example.owl;

import java.io.File;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.AxiomType;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectProperty;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

public class IterateOWLDetails2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
            IRI iri = IRI.create(new File("src/main/webapp/resources/inputfile/owlfile/pizza.owl"));
            OWLOntology moduleOWL = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri);

            java.util.Set<OWLClass> classes;
            java.util.Set<OWLObjectProperty> prop;
            java.util.Set<OWLDataProperty> dataProp;
            java.util.Set<OWLNamedIndividual> individuals;

            classes = moduleOWL.getClassesInSignature();
            prop = moduleOWL.getObjectPropertiesInSignature();
            dataProp = moduleOWL.getDataPropertiesInSignature();
            individuals = moduleOWL.getIndividualsInSignature();

            System.out.println("Classes");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            for (OWLClass cls : classes) {
                System.out.println("+: " + cls.getIRI().getShortForm());

                System.out.println(" \tObject Property Domain");
                for (OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom op : moduleOWL.getAxioms(AxiomType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_DOMAIN)) {
                    if (op.getDomain().equals(cls)) {
                        for (OWLObjectProperty oop : op.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()) {
                            if (cls.getIRI().getShortForm().equals(oop.getIRI().getShortForm()))
                                continue;
                            System.out.println("\t\t +: " + oop.getIRI().getShortForm() + "==Object Property");
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(" \tData Property Domain");
                for (OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom dp : moduleOWL.getAxioms(AxiomType.DATA_PROPERTY_DOMAIN)) {
                    if (dp.getDomain().equals(cls)) {
                        for (OWLDataProperty odp : dp.getDataPropertiesInSignature()) {
                            System.out.println("\t\t +: " + odp.getIRI().getShortForm() + "==Data Property");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } // end try

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load ontology/ies");
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch`
    }
}
```

I have data like below

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasBase">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasIngredient"/>
        <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#isBaseOf"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#InverseFunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Pizza"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#PizzaBase"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I need to get domain, range, sub property from the file. I don't have subclass property in my file so please don't give solutions as using the list subclass method of ontology.
I have iterated all the classes now I have to get the various property of that class like domain, range,sub-property, etc. of the iterated class.

Comment: I don't understand why you're iterating over classes then...you want to have all information about each property, for sure you should iterate over the properties. Especially your statement *"I am only getting [class] and it's [sub-property]"* doesn't make sense, what would be the subproperty of a class?! Classes have subclasses.

Comment: In addition, objects of type `OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom` (`OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom`) have dedicated methods to get the property, called `getProperty()`

Comment: *"now I have to get the various property of that class like domain, range,sub-property,"* -> that is a totally wrong statement! A class does **not** "have" those things you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for reply @AKSW yes that was my mistake class does not have domain range and subproperty it&#39;s a object property  that has all that things and I need to add those property for my requirements like i want to store this all details in map and then I want to get this property for making ttl file by comparing XML data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have printed my output using below code it's now solved my question
like this way using property getObjectPropertyRangeAxioms(oop)

```
for(OWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom range:moduleOWL.getObjectPropertyRangeAxioms(oop)) {
    for(OWLEntity rangeStr : range.getSignature()) {
    //System.out.println("\t\t ==========: " + rangeStr );
    if(!rangeStr.containsEntityInSignature(oop)) {
     System.out.println("\t\t -: " + rangeStr.toString().replaceAll("<|>", "") );
     str = rangeStr.toString().replaceAll("<|>", "");
    }
    }
}
```